# Permission Denied Error in Linux Terminal

Tags: installation, permissions, fedora

I am getting a `Permission denied` error while executing the `sh INSTALL.sh` command in my Linux terminal.

Can any one suggest me how to solve this problem? I getting this error while am installing 94 POS Software.

The piece of code is

> INSTALL.sh: line 75: toolchain/INSTALL: Permission denied
>   INSTALL.sh: line 76: download/INSTALL.sh: Permission denied
>   INSTALL.sh: line 85: export: /usr/local/arm-
>   linux/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/manohar/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: This isn't a programming question, please read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This will probably do you more harm than good, but try `sudo ./INSTALL.sh`.

Comment: By default sudo isn't enabled, try `su -c 'INSTALL.sh'`. It will ask your password.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `sudo` to run that.

Run this command inside the directory which contains the file you want to run.

> `sudo ./INSTALL.sh`

If `sudo` ins't enabled, you can run `su -c ./INSTALL.sh`

Comment: Also, this needs `INSTALL.sh` to have execute permissions. If it doesn't work, you'd need to run `sudo chmod +x INSTALL.sh`.